# Amend theme php to include certain category in header

Tags: php, themes, homepage

I'm using a free theme on my WordPress site, and the `index.php` is the following:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $total_post_count = wp_count_posts();
    $published_post_count = $total_post_count->publish;
    $total_pages = ceil( $published_post_count / $posts_per_page );

    if ( "1" < $paged ) : ?>

        <div class="page-title">

            <h4><?php printf( __('Page %s of %s', 'hitchcock'), $paged, $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?></h4>

        </div> <!-- /page-title -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="posts" id="posts">


        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; ?>


            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div> <!-- /posts -->

<?php endif; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php hitchcock_archive_navigation(); ?>
```

This shows the latest posts on my website. I want to amend this code to only show posts from a certain category instead. Is this something that I can just amend or add code?

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention, that I have actually done a fair amount of research, and tried out quite a few bits of code to try and make this work, but nothing's worked yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action `pre_get_posts`. It gets fired after the query object is created but before the query is run.

This is an example from the official documentary for displaying only one category:

In your `functions.php` add the following:

```
function my_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '123' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```

Comment: Perfect!  Works!  Exactly what I wanted, and I would never have worked this out!  Thanks Alex :)  quick accurate response, exactly what I wanted.